# Trying to do Scala WS calls in a given ExecutionContext

Tags: scala, playframework, concurrency

I have a project which does HTTP calls to two seperate API's. The calls to both of these API's need to be rate limited separately. I started with the calls to one of the API's and I'm trying to use a custom ExecutionContext to achieve this. Here's my application.conf:

```
play.modules.enabled += "playtest.PlayTestModule"

my-context {
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-min = 10
    parallelism-max = 10
  }
}
```

This is the scala class I'm using to test if it works:

```
@Singleton
class MyWsClient @Inject() (client: WSClient, akkaSystem: ActorSystem) {

   val myExecutionContext: ExecutionContext = akkaSystem.dispatchers.lookup("my-context")
   val i = new AtomicInteger(0)

   def doThing: Future[Int] = {
      Future {
         println(i.incrementAndGet)
         println("Awaiting")
         Await.result(client.url("http://localhost:9000/test").get, Duration.Inf)
         println("Done")
         i.decrementAndGet
         1
      }(myExecutionContext)
   }
}
```

However, no matter what I try, the number of parallel calls exceeds the limits I set in the application.conf. But it gets even stranger, because if I replace the line

```
Await.result(client.url("http://localhost:9000/test").get, Duration.Inf)
```

with

```
Thread.sleep(1000)
```

the limits ARE respected and the rate is properly limited.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? If there is another way of rate limiting with the scala-ws library I would love to hear it.

Comment: You mean the number of **parallel** calls exceeds the limits?

Comment: @SergeyKovalev yes that is correct. Changed the text in the question

Comment: That's the thing with non-blocking: it doesn't need a thread per request. Libraries like the async-http-client support rate limiting though: https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/3e78a04d58ab904fe668d0cf4c09b31ba7437500/extras/guava/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/extras/guava/RateLimitedThrottleRequestFilter.java

Comment: @rethab Using await.result makes the thing blocking, so I don't understand why this doesn't work. Another library having support is nice, but do you know if the Scala-ws client has built-in support for rate limiting as well? Because that's what I'm trying to use.

Comment: I believe `Await.result` tells the thread pool that it's blocking and depending on the implementation, it might decide to resize itself. Not sure whether the limits you set with `parallelism-max` are respected in that case.

Comment: @rethab I agree, that's my suspicion as well. I just wish I knew how to do it right without having to use a completely different library

Comment: Rate limiting is a function of time and that's not how fork join executors work. If your goal is to have a number of concurrency you can control with a thread pool consider using the `thread-pool-executor` or if you want true rate limiting see Fredric A.'s answer

Answer (score 3):

I understand you want to keep using `scala-ws` ok, but what about something not relying on using specific `ExecutionContext`?

If you agree with that here's an idea... You create a `RateLimitedWSClient` component, which you will inject into your controllers instead of `WSClient`. This component should be a singleton, and support a single method `def rateLimit[R](rateLimitClass: String)(request: WSClient => Future[R])`. The `rateLimitClass` is meant to specify which ratelimit to apply to the current `request`, as you said you need to rate-limit requests to different API differently. The `request` function should be obvious.

Now my suggestion for the implementation is to use a simple akka-stream that will pipe your `request`s through the actual `WSClient` while rate-limiting using the `throttle` flow-stage (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#throttle):

```
val client: WSClient = ??? // injected into the component
// component initialization, for example create one flow per API
val queue = 
  Source
  .queue[(Promise[_], WSClient => Future[_])](...) // keep this materialized value
  .throttle(...)
  .map { (promise, request) => 
    promise.completeWith(request(client))
  }
  .to(Sink.ignore)
  .run() // You have to get the materialized queue out of here!

def rateLimit[R](rateLimitClass: String)(request: WSClient => Future[R]): Future[R] = {
  val result = Promise.empty[R]
  // select which queue to use based on rateLimitClass
  if (rateLimitClass == "API1")
    queue.offer(result -> request)
  else ???
  result.future
}
```

The above is only rough code, I hope you get the idea. You can of course choose something else that a queue, or if you keep the queue, you have to decide how to handle overflows...